# Getting a different color from already seen

Tags: java, css, algorithm, graphics, colors

this may be a strange question, but as for your knoledge, is there a way to **automatically** calculate a color which is substantialy different from others?

Let me explain better: I need to sample the position of moving robots on a 2D-map every X timesteps. In order to be able to visualize where different robots have been, I'd like to color points differently. Every robot with a different color.

The point is that the number of robots may vary(from 1 to many) and I it would be really great to have an automatic way to automatically assign **substantially** different colors to different for the human vision system.

What do I mean by substantially? I mean that they should be as much more different as possibile. Blue and Red are different while 2 different shades of Red no.

It is obvious that as the number of robots grows, the color will be less and less distinguishable, but what I would like is to maximaze the differences between the colors, in order to be able to distinguish them better.

Thank you very much,

Marco

Comment: I think your problem is analogous to wanting n maximally-spaced points in 3D space. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34968/point-cloud-that-maximizes-the-minimum-pairwise-distance-in-euclidean-space

Comment: That may be a nice solution! I'll try and see! Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/where-can-i-find-a-large-palette-set-of-contrasting-colors-for-coloring-many-d